# How to view the binary contents of environment variables?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I'm practicing CTFs (capture-the-flag) and want to view the contents of an environment variable:

```
MyEnv=`python3 -c 'print(64*"A"+"\x0a\x09\x0a\x0d",end="")'`
```

Now, `hexdump` displays the following, when piping the input using `echo`:

```
$ echo -n $MyEnv | hexdump -Cv
00000000  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000010  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000020  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000030  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000040  20 0d                                             | .|
00000042
```

It properly has to do with `echo` not willing to print the last four hex-digits.

However, I know that `MyEnv` contains the last four digits, because it solves the exercise.

How can I display the binary contents of an environment variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it has to do with the unquoted `$MyEnv` variable being split on and trimmed of runs of characters[1] from the `IFS` variable, which by default are space (`\x20`), tab (`\x09`) and newline (`\x0a`), and then `echo` writing the fields it was split into joined with spaces (`\x20`).

In order to be able to view those characters, quote the `$MyEnv` variable, and use `printf` instead of `echo -n`[2]

```
$ printf %s "$MyEnv" | hexdump -Cv
...
00000040  0a 09 0a 0d                                       |....|
00000044
```

Notice that generally you cannot store binary data in environment variables -- binary data can contain NUL bytes (`\0`), and the values of environment variables are zero-terminated strings. NUL bytes also don't work in `bash`'s internal (non-exported) variables.

[1] If the character from the IFS is not "white space", the shell may actually split on a single character and create empty fields. Complete description in the [Field Splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) section of the standard.

[2] The `echo` from a standard shell may interpret some backslash escapes (eg. `\n` to newline, etc), possibly messing your variable even more.

Comment: Thank you. Would you elaborate on IFS? So the first hex values (\x0a \x09 \x0a) are replaced by \x20 in my hexdump output? Could I quote MyEnv and still use echo somehow?

Comment: Your variable will be split into `\x41\x41...\x41` and `\x0d` which will be passed as parameters to `echo -n`, which will print them joined by a space (`\x20`) to stdout.

Comment: with `bash` you can use `echo -n` instead of `printf %s`, but other shells (eg. `/bin/sh` on debian, ubuntu, etc) will interpret backslash escapes in the variable's value; example on debian: `a='\033[41;37mFOO\nBAR\033[m' sh -c 'echo "$a"'`.